# 1st Yr Probability question: need help proving a statement

Tags: probability

Is there a way to prove this "algebraically"?

$P(X \le a, Y \le b) + P(X \le a, Y > b) = P(X \le a, Y < \infty)$

**Can you help me with the full, pedantic, for dummies proof?**

Do not use proof by venn diagram or proof by drawing.

---

My attempts:

1. I know $P(Y \le b) = 1 - P(Y > b)$ which follows because of the 3rd axiom of probability and the definition of a complement. But I don't know how to fit this in with the other RV $X$
2. Maybe it's a proof similar to $A = AB \cup AB^c$ where you go LHS to RHS and RHS to LHS...
3. I tried using the inclusion exclusion rule on $P(X \le a, Y > b)$ after taking the complement but I'm just going in circles.

Thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, then $P(A)+P(B)=P(A \cup B)$ (this is an axiom). Here, $A=\{X \le a, Y \le b\}$ and $B=\{X \le a, Y > b\}$.

Comment: Ah... I never thought about defining an event for the regions of X and Y like that... your proof is satisfying for me. Thank you!!